# Как передать полученное значение из формы в функции в другую функцию? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form

У меня в `App()` в **return** выводится форма из `HandleInput()`, там есть параметр **input**, мне его нужно передать в `App()` для подальшего взаимодействия.

Иными словами, чтобы можно было взаимодействовать в функции `App()` с полученными данными из инпута в функции `HandleInput()`

В функции `App()` нужно чтобы вместо **"Animated text"** был параметр **input**

**index.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import "./index.css";

function HandleInput() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    name="text"
                    value={input}
                    placeholder="Input text"
                    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                />
                <br />
                
                <input 
                    type="submit"
                    value="Submit"
                />
            </form>

            <p>Output: {input}</p>
        </>
    )
}

function App() {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const fullWord = "Animated text ";

    const word = Array.from(fullWord);

    const showTextWithTimeout = () => {
        if (counter >= 0 && counter < word.length-1) {
            setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
        } 
        else {
            setCounter((counter) => counter = 0);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            showTextWithTimeout();
            
            if (counter >= 0 && counter < word.length-1) {
                setText(text + word[counter]);
            }

            else if (counter === word.length-1) {
                setText("");
            }   
        
        }, 200);
    })

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <HandleInput />

            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынеси в App состояние:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
```

и когда будешь рендерить элемент **HandleInput** в **App** передавай состояние пропсами. Должно выглядеть что-то на подобии этого

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  return (
    ...другие компоненты
    <HandleInput 
      input={input}
      setInput={setInput}
    />
    ...другие компоненты
  )
}
```

**HandleInput.js**

```
const HandleInput = ({ input, setInput }) => {
  return (
    <>
      ...другие компоненты
      <input
        name="text"
        value={input}
        placeholder="Input text"
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      ...другие компоненты
    </>
  )
}
```